# Android Studio won't open after update

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, window

After updating Android Studio I can't open, all the time it show me this error message. Before I haven't any problems, it is first time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Android studio might be corrupted.
**Uninstall** and **re-install** the latest version.  Your problem will be solved.

Comment: I would try uninstalling just the Emulator and reinstalling it to see if that solves it, before you do a complete uninstall of Android Studio.